# Parsing XML using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to parse the following xml structure using DOM.

```
<body>
<para> The Constitution of India is the supreme law of India.[1] It lays down the framework defining fundamental political principles, establishes the structure, procedures, powers and duties of government institutions and sets out fundamental rights, directive principles and the duties of citizens.</para>
<sec>
<title>INTRODUCTION</title>
<para>The major portion of the Indian subcontinent was under British rule from 1857 to 1947. When the Constitution of India came into force on 26 January 1950, it repealed the Indian Independence Act. India ceased to be a dominion of the British Crown and became a sovereign democratic republic. The date of 26 January was chosen to commemorate the Purna Swaraj declaration of independence of 1930.</para>
</sec>
</body>
```

The code looks like:

```
 Element bodyElem = doc.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
Element secElem = bodyElem.getElementsByTagName("sec").item(0);
String title = secElem.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
String para = secElem.getElementsByTagName("para").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Here if I am taking tag 'para' all paras are coming together. But I want in separate sections like..

The Constitution of India is the supreme law of India.[1] It lays down the framework defining fundamental political principles, establishes the structure, procedures, powers and duties of government institutions and sets out fundamental rights, directive principles and the duties of citizens.
INTRODUCTION - The major portion of the Indian subcontinent was under British rule from 1857 to 1947. When the Constitution of India came into force on 26 January 1950, it repealed the Indian Independence Act. India ceased to be a dominion of the British Crown and became a sovereign democratic republic. The date of 26 January was chosen to commemorate the Purna Swaraj declaration of independence of 1930.

What Can I do for taking the tags separately (tags with sane name) under different tags but in a common parent tag..

Comment: Use SAX-Parser , which will give you a object representation for your xml.

Comment: I wanted to do using DOM

Comment: How do you decide to put the content to a different tag if the tags all have the same name ?

Comment: Like.. if that particular tag(here 'para') is coming under 'sec' (which also has a 'title' tag) I will put these values(title,para) into map.. Otherwise 'para' is added to stringbuffer

Comment: Oh, yeah in that case that should be possible. You can use something like `NodeList nodelist = doc.getChildNodes()` to get all elements. Then you check for each element in that list if there is a "para". If there is a "para", look if the previous element was a "sec" or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath or a CSS selector might be a better choice.